# FindDuplicatesByIds Class

Tags: apex, duplicate-management

I am reading through the 'FindDuplicatesByID Class' documentation, and have a general question.

When I run the example code given, I am triggering the 'System.debug('Found duplicates') line because the ...idList.size() > 0, even though this is not a duplicate account (I am using the standard account matching rules).

Can someone please explain why this is? Shouldn't it be returning the value '0' since it is not a duplicate record?

```
Account acct = new Account(name='Salesforce');
insert acct;

List<Id> idList = new List<Id>();
idList.add(acct.id);

if (Datacloud.FindDuplicatesByIds.​findDuplicatesByIds(idList).size() ​> 0) {
System.debug('Found duplicates');
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to example code provided in the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Datacloud_FindDuplicatesByIds.htm). From what I can tell, the line

> System.debug('Found duplicates');

can be regarded as a mistake of the documentation - because the size of *this* list doesn't have anything to do with the number of duplicates and probably (as you observed) you've got no duplicate Account at all. The explanatory text of the documentation however is more precise:

> The output of FindDuplicatesByIds is an array of objects with the same number of elements as the input array...

If you are looking for a true duplicate check - the [documentation of FindDuplicatesResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Datacloud_FindDuplicatesResult.htm)  seems to provide an accurate code example.